# Styling the Ember rootElement

Tags: ember.js

I've been banging my head against this for over a day and no amount of experimenting, Google'ing, or Stack Overflow searching has helped.

I'm developing an Ember/Vert.x app that has one Ember Route that accepts "real-time" push-data via SocksJS.  This is working beautifully, including the successful implementation of dynamic (Ember) templates.

What I need now is the ability to set styles on the rootElement (rootElement is body).  I've tried umpteen different approaches, including resorting to jQuery calls.  Nothing will place a style on the body tag.  I CAN get the style attribute set on the *1st div inside the body tag* by doing:

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  attributeBindings:  ['style'],
  style: "background-color: blue; background-image: url('" + App.currentProgram.backgroundImage + "')"
});
```

This renders:

```
<div id="ember325" class="ember-view" style="background-image: url('img/bg/1.png')">...</div>
```

However, I really want to style the ***body*** tag dynamically.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated as this is a blocking item for my prototype client demo next week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `didInsertElement` method, to know when the dom is inserted, and update the body element using `this.$().parent()`.

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        this._super();        
        this.$().parent().css({
            "background-color": "blue",
            "background-image": "url('" + App.currentProgram.backgroundImage + "')"
        });
    }
})
```

Live sample http://jsfiddle.net/X5TmH/

Comment: This works perfectly!  For others looking for this, it's beautifully simple.  Fantastic job, Marcio, and thanks!